# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to run an application

Tags: object, reference, null, instance

I am getting this error very frequently, I have to clean the solution, Build, Rebuilt over and over until this error disappears for a while, then I can continue working and It happends again. Today I've have lost at least one and a half hour just trying to run the application. Could somebody tell me why is happening this and how could I solve it? This is driving me crazy, I am losing to much time because of this, any help would be appreciated.

Here you can see an image of the error.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64119484-7dfa-4d75-8ee1-c60314cc0a25/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-when-trying-to-run-an-application?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: What language?  No idea based on what you posted.

Comment: Sorry, VB.NET, but the error is on Visual Studio when I try to run the application, the error appears on the output/error list and it's happening very frequently but not every time so it's not a code error.

Comment: "it's happening very frequently but not every time so it's not a code error" - check your assumptions.  Can you step into the method in a debugger and see what the reference is pointing to?

Comment: There is no code line, the application is not even running, see this image https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=8b7770aadee49b2b#cid=8B7770AADEE49B2B&id=8B7770AADEE49B2B%21174&v=3